# How do I make a large number of random arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, function, hash

I need to make an array that has 8000 random integers between values 0 - 65535 for a hash table assignment, I understand the math.random function but how do I get random numbers for such a large range of numbers? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 7):

If you're in Java 8, you can write

```
int[] array = new Random().ints(0, 65536).limit(8000).toArray();
```

otherwise you'd just write something like

```
int[] array = new int[8000];
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
  array[i] = rng.nextInt(65536);
}
```

Comment: @SleimanJneidi, it sounds like this is a part of a bigger assignment involving hash tables?

Comment: yeah but the student didn't show any effort, why should we provide ready snippets here?